# Passing shell variables into mysql queries

Tags: mysql, shell

I'm updating a purge script to either delete all rows or a single row, so this will be controlled by a variable called DEVICE so question is can I use (*) as variable name? DEVICE might by `*` (all) or `12.3.4.5` (a single device).

```
DELETE L from LogTable L WHERE L.logTime < @cutoffTime AND L.deviceAddress = "${DEVICE}";
```

Comment: So this is some kind of SQL? What dialect? What shell are you using? The first line is pseudocode? Please clarify.

Comment: The first line is pseudocode, I should have used wildcard not Regular Expression.

Comment: I also found I should be using LIKE instead of equals in the mysql delete

Comment: So you plan to write a shell script, but at some point change to pseudocode and then to some unknown SQL? The question contains more unspecified things than question.

Comment: Sorry I should have bee more clear in question something like how to pass a wildcard in a variable maybe

Comment: please consider editing your question so it addresses these comments. Having to dig through all the comments is not helpful. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> question is can I use (*) as variable name?
>
> ```
> DEVICE=* (all) or DEVICE=12.3.4.5 (single)
> ```

You mean: *can I use `*` as variable **value***.

You can, and you correctly quoted the expansion in your example.